# Change e-mail used to send Google Calendar invites

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

I have two emails `a@gmail.com` and `b@work.com` linked to Gmail from which I can send emails. Now in Google calendar I can send calendar invites to emails, which are sent by `a@gmail.com` (It says `a@gmail.com` has invited you, please reply to `a@gmail.com`), as this is my main email and I'm the owner of this calendar.

I cannot find an option to change the email used in the invites, I even tried to create a new calendar for work appointments which belongs to `b@work.com` but this is also not possible as `a@gmail.com` is used per default and is not changeable.

My question now is how to send invitations in the name of my alternative email `b@work.com` and with the reply path `b@work.com`, or how to create a new calendar for this email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`@work.com`** is not a valid Gmail domain so this can't be done.

If **`@work.com`** was just an example of **`work@gmail.com`** then all you need to do is log out from **`a@gmail.com`** account and log in to **`work@gmail.com`** and send your invites from there. This is the only way.

Comment: no, it's my corporate email. Too bad...